# How to setup connection from Win8 to ubuntu 18.04 via serial port RS232

Tags: ubuntu, serial-port

I would like to connect from my Microsoft's Windows 8 PC, to a PLC(Advantech uno-2372g), via USB-to-RS232 to a serial port on the PLC (ttyS0),
using putty. I am trying to connect to the PLC, but it does not work.

How do I setup the ubuntu side to listen on serial port ttyS0?

Comment: Are you using “SSH” in a generic sense, like the way we say “Jell-O” for any gelatin desserts, or do you really mean “SSH”?  Connecting and logging in via a serial port might not be very hard, but it wouldn’t be SSH.

Comment: SSH as connection. :-)
i have a serial port RS232 on the PLC and i would like to connect to the terminal (CLI) via the serial port from my Win8 to the PLC.

Comment: Insecure (just a connection to a terminal, no `ssh`), is easy, it was done a lot in the past (at one time it was the only way to connect to a computer). `ssh` over RS232 should not be much harder (but I have never done it). Can you clarify on what you need, what are your priorities? (If you have physical security, then you may not need encryption).

Comment: I need just to establish a connection to the PLC terminal (CLI) using PC Win8 via USB to RS232 to the serial port on the PLC.
security is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

On the Ubuntu side, you would typically do this (assuming you have GRUB2 and systemd):

If you configure the serial console in GRUB2 systemd will create a getty listener on the same serial device as GRUB2 by default. So, this is the only configuration needed for Linux running with systemd. To make grub enable the serial console, open `/etc/default/grub` in an editor. Change the `GRUB_CMDLINE_DEFAULT` line to start the console on `/dev/ttyS0`. Note in the example below, we set two consoles up; one on `tty0` and one on the serial port.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="console=tty0 console=ttyS0,38400n8"
```

Now we need to tell grub where is the console and what command to start in order to enable the serial console (Note as above for Linux kernel, one can append multiple input/output terminals in grub e.g. `GRUB_TERMINAL="console serial"` would enable both display and serial):

```
## Serial console
GRUB_TERMINAL=serial
GRUB_SERIAL_COMMAND="serial --speed=38400 --unit=0 --word=8 --parity=no --stop=1"
```

Rebuild the `grub.cfg` file with following command:

```
# grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

After a reboot, getty will be listening on `/dev/ttyS0`, expecting `38400` baud, 8 data bits, no parity and one stop bit. When the system boots, `systemd` will automatically start a getty session to listen on the same device with the same settings.

In PuTTY, you would select `serial` and enter `38400` baud speed.